# How to Convert MultiDimensional Array to Single Dimensional array in C#?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have one multi-dimensional array which contains binary data as [3,240]:

```
byte[,] bData = (byte[,])objTran; // bdata is binary data with [3,240]
```

which means it has 3 records each from 0,239 and 1,239 and 2,239.
Now I am Marshalling this data to copy in TRANSACTIONLOGINFO structure:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bData, GCHandleType.Pinned);

TRANSACTIONLOGINFO ObjTranInfo = (TRANSACTIONLOGINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
    handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(TRANSACTIONLOGINFO));

handle.Free();
```

But every time `ObjTranInfo` shows only the first data details. How can I convert the multi-dimensional array to a single-dimensional array and pass to `GCHandle` to get each data one by one?

Comment: What is `TRANSACTIONLOGINFO`? You sure it is not an array of structures?

Comment: TRANSACTIONLOGINFO is a structure

Comment: objTran contains binary data.

Comment: @user662285: Well show us what `TRANSACTIONLOGINFO` looks like...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single-dimensional byte array of the right size (in your case 240) and copy the data across a byte at a time using a `for` loop. Repeat this for every row of the original two-dimensional array.